# How can I collect shipping information?

Tags: commerce, 10

I can't figure out how to get the shipping address information to be collected on checkout in Commerce on Drupal 10.

My setup

- Created a Manual payment gateway that collects billing information.
- Installed the [Commerce Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) module (version 2.6).
- On `/admin/commerce/config/order-types/default/edit`, set **Workflow** to *Fulfillment*,  checked the box **Enable shipping for this order type**, and set the **Checkout flow** to *Shipping* as instructed in the module README.
- Added four different flat rate shipping methods at `/admin/commerce/shipping-methods`.  None of the shipping methods have any conditions to limit visibility; they should all be shown.

However, when I add a product to the cart and then go to checkout, shipping information is never displayed.  I do see the payment information (to input a billing address) and contact information (input an email).  This happens both for anonymous and logged-in users (even user 1, so it's not a permissions issue).

The Shipping checkout flow has "Shipping information" under **Order information**, which is the default configuration.

Comment: Have you enabled the "Shippable" trait on the product variation type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you enabled the "Shippable" trait on the product variation type?